# Performance difference between built in magnitude function and this code

Tags: math, directx, directx-10

Is there a big difference between using the DirectX vector magnitude math function as opposed to the following code?

```
float hyp = sqrt(pow(globalVector.x, 2) + pow(globalVector.y, 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough for you to care.

There are improvements that I'd recommend to the function you posted.

No need to call the power function; `x*x` and `y*y` will be just as good and cheaper.

I'd protect against roundoff by scaling, like this pseudo code:

```
if (abs(x) > abs(y)) {
   r = abs(y/x);
   hyp = x*sqrt(1 + r*r);
} else {
    r = abs(x/y);
    hyp = y*sqrt(1 + r*r);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by - protect against round off by scaling?

Comment: You ought to look into it.  If either x or y (or both) are very large, squaring large numbers and adding them to smaller ones can result in a loss of precision.  A double only has about 18 digits of precision.  So if you scale the problem in such a way that you never square a very large number.